# Put SqlCeDataReader output into a string (C#)

Tags: c#, .net, windows

At the moment I am only able to output this to a string, although I have tried creating an array and using int[] but it does not like it at all. How could the output of `reader.GetInt32(0)` be put into an array?

```
com.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", Form1.date);
SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
while (reader.Read())
{
    int resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);
    MessageBox.Show(resultsoutput.ToString());
}
```

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @Haris Hasan To get all of the returned values into an array

Comment: @Mike: your title and (apparent) question do not match... How exactly do you want it put into an array? As a 1 element array? Is the result column supposed to be an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
        List<int> results = new List<int>();
        com.Parameters.AddWithValue("date", Form1.date);
        SqlCeDataReader reader = com.ExecuteReader();
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            int resultsoutput = reader.GetInt32(0);

            results.Add(resultsoutput);
            // I wouldn't use a MessageBox in this loop
            // MessageBox.Show(resultsoutput.ToString());
        }
```

Add it to a collection

Comment: Can you define the maximum amount of entries in the list with this method?

Comment: No, but you could add some logic in the loop to break when you reached your limit. Or add a TOP 20 to your SQL.

Comment: Ahh I see, how then would I call a specific entry in the list?

Comment: results[3] or results[whatever]

Answer (score 1):

`reader.GetInt32(0);` only reads the first column. To read all columns into an array use  `GetValues()`.

```
using System.Linq;
// ...
while (reader.Read())
{
    Object[] values = new Object[reader.FieldCount];
    int fieldCount = reader.GetValues(values);
    values.ToList().ForEach(value => results.Add(parseInt(value));
}
```